# how many numbers of n digits in a mobile number pad

Tags: dynamic-programming, backtracking

if we are given a mobile phone with number pad as
     
9 8 7
     
6 5 4
     
3 2 1
     
* 0 #

and a number n , then how many numbers of n digit we can make my typing in keypad , we can not move diagonally from a previously chosen number  i.e from if we have typed 9 the next no i can choose is 8 or 6 . Also number like 082 will be count as 2 digit number not 3.

sample test case
 
input n = 1  output = 9
 
input n = 2  output = 25

I am unable to formulate a dynamic programming/backtracking solution for it .

Answer (score 0):

Let `f(n)` be the list of all sequences composed of `n` digits.:

- The base case is simple: `f(1) = [ 1, 2, ..., 9 ]`.
- In the general case, how can you compute `f(n)` from `f(n-1)`? Simply loop over the elements of `f(n-1)` and check the last digit. Say `f(2)` contains `85`, then `f(3)` should contain 852, 854 856, and 858. Add all these new elements in a new list and return it.